# What are the options for travelling from Belfast airport to Sligo?

Tags: uk, trains, buses, ireland, timetables

I'm looking to land at Belfast International Airport at around 2055 and would like to travel to Sligo the same day.

What are the best options for getting there?

I'm having difficulty finding a decent train/bus route, but may be looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Even by car, it is almost 3 hours to drive. It is not realistic to manage that trip with public transport the same evening.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo With slightly more explanation, that sounded like an answer.

Comment: @B.Liu But I am not sure. There are indeed some bus services, at least in Northern Ireland, which still operate very late. E.g. the last bus from Belfast to Derry departs 1:00am and arrives 2:40am. It might very well be, that someone more familiar with the bus routes in that region may have a suggestion. I am just saying that it is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have three options [according to Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Belfast/Sligo):

- Drive.  2 hours 18ish, you'd need to rent a car from the airport.
- Train. 6 hours 20ish.  Unfortunately doesn't leave until the morning.
- Bus. 4 hours 23ish. Also unforrtunately, no services until the next morning.

The costs, times and departures vary, [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Belfast/Sligo) shows you the various options.